# How to send variable value via email with smtplib in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, smtplib

I am able to send email when the message is a string directly typed into the function, but not when it is a variable.

This code works:

```
import smtplib

server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
server.login("something@gmail.com", "somepassword")

server.sendmail(
"something@gmail.com", 
"somethingelse@gmail.com", 
"a manually typed string like this")
server.quit()
```

But this code, with a variable string, doesn't:

```
import smtplib

server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
server.login("something@gmail.com", "somepassword")

someVariable = "any string"

server.sendmail(
"something@gmail.com", 
"somethingelse@gmail.com", 
someVariable)
server.quit()
```

More exactly, this second version does send an email but with an empty body. No characters show up.

How can I make the second version work?

`print(someVariable)` and `print(type(someVariable))` give the right (expected) outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this worked, inspired by `[these docs][1]` and by rogersdevop's earlier answer (which didn't work for me):

def sendEmail(msge):

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

msg = MIMEText(msge)

me = 'something@gmail.com'
you = 'somethingelse@gmail.com'
msg['Subject'] = 'The subject line'
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you

s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
s.login("something@gmail.com", "somepassword")
s.send_message(msg)
s.quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

My personal experience with Office365 led me to this solution:

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

msg = MIMEMultipart()

msg['Subject'] = 'confirmation email'
msg['From'] = 'my.address@email.net'
msg['To'] = ", ".join(['your.address@email.net','another.address@email.net'])

body = 'Example email text here.'

msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'html')) #set to whatever text format is preferred
```

And then the final piece of how it fits with your current script

```
server.sendmail('my.address@email.net','your.address@email.net',msg.as_string())
```

Comment: Thank you. The last line gives the following error: Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'MIMEMultipart' object has no attribute 'to_string'.

Comment: Sorry about that - the method name is actually .as_string(), going off of memory. Glad you were able to find your solution regardless!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
import smtplib

server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
server.login("something@gmail.com", "somepassword")

server.sendmail(
"something@gmail.com", 
"somethingelse@gmail.com", 
"{}".format(someVariable))
server.quit()
```

I imagine that you just need to format whatever the variable is into a string

Comment: This doesn't change the result. The email is still sent and still empty. Note that the type of "someVariable" is indeed string.