# Python smtplib - not sending with variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtplib

I am trying to send an email using the smtplib library. It works fine, but if my message includes a fixed string + variable, it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
destinationEmail = 'destination@gmail.com'
server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587) 
server.starttls() 
server.login("me@gmail.com", "password") 
message = f"I am sending this variable: {variableName}" 
server.sendmail("me@gmail.com", destinationEmail, message)
```

Using the above code does not work. I've tried using this format for the message as well:

```
message = "I am sending this variable: " + variableName
```

It also does not work. If my message has no variables, it sends successfully, like:

```
message = "testing"
```

Another thing I've tried is sending the variable alone, like:

```
message = variableName
```

And that works! So I'm really confused what is wrong here. It seems like it doesn't wanna send messages that has a fixed string + variable. BTW the variable I am using is of type string. Even when I use str( ) around the variable, it doesn't work.

Comment: The code you show above must work.  They're just strings.  You have some other problem here.  Perhaps you should show us real code.  Now `f"xxx"` strings are a relatively recent addition to the language.  If you have a very old Python, they won't work, but you'd get a syntax error.

Comment: Could you clarify more about how it doesn't work? Does it throw an error or does it send unexpected message?

Comment: 'real code' what do you mean lol? The code I posted is exactly what I'm running, I only changed the emails and password (obviously...). Yep f-strings are new, which is why I tried out string concatenation as well. I'm using python 3.10 btw.

Comment: @taxevader No error is thrown. It runs successfully. The email is just never received at the destination

Comment: I think smtp gmail requires `Subject:` header in order to send the message probably. Otherwise, it would be acting pretty unpredictable. Could you try changing the `message` to `message = "Subject: Some subject\n\nI am sending this variable: " + variableName` instead of `message = "I am sending this variable: " + variableName`. Does that work?

Comment: I'm an idiot :( I figured it out, this helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54374258/how-to-send-variable-value-via-email-with-smtplib-in-python3

Answer (score 0):

This is usually a version problem, but you can always substitute your f-string for `message = "I am sending this variable: {}".format(variable_name)` which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here: [How to send variable value via email with smtplib in python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54374258/how-to-send-variable-value-via-email-with-smtplib-in-python3)

Use MIMEText to construct the message (with 'subject' 'from' and 'to'). @tax evader was right about the subject thing. I guess it requires a subject.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).